# External access to apache virtual host

Tags: apache, networking, virtualhost

I've set up an Apache server on a computer in my home network and enabled name-based virtual hosting.

I've configured the host files on my local network machines, enabled port forwarding on the router and configured the DNS.

I would like to be able to access the virtual host both from within the network and also externally.

`192.168.0.2` is the IP address of the virtual host and `1.2.3.4` is the external IP address.

With the following configuration in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.my-hostname.com
    ServerAlias my-hostname.com
    DocumentRoot "<path-to-doc-root>"
        <Directory "<path-to-doc-root>"">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From the virtual host machine:

- `192.168.0.2` gets me the apache main server 'It works!' page.
- `1.2.3.4` gets me 'The requested URL /UI was not found on this server.'
- `my-hostname.com` gets me the virtual host.

From a different machine inside the network:

- `192.168.0.2` gets me the apache main server 'It works!' page.
- `1.2.3.4` gets me the apache main server 'It works!' page.
- `my-hostname.com` gets me the virtual host.

From an external machine:

- `1.2.3.4` gets me the apache main server 'It works!' page.
- `my-hostname.com` gets me the apache main server 'It works!' page.

If I change the configuration (as suggested on the apache website) to:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.2  1.2.3.4>
    ServerName www.my-hostname.com
    ServerAlias my-hostname.com
    DocumentRoot "<path-to-doc-root>"
        <Directory "<path-to-doc-root>"">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From the virtual host machine:

- `192.168.0.2` gets me the apache main server 'It works!' page.
- `1.2.3.4` gets me 'The requested URL /UI was not found on this server.'
- my-hostname.com gets me the apache main server 'It works!' page.

From a different machine inside the network:

- `192.168.0.2` gets me the virtual host.
- `1.2.3.4` gets me the apache main server 'It works!' page.
- `my-hostname.com` gets me the virtual host.

From an external machine:

- `1.2.3.4` gets me the virtual host.
- `my-hostname.com` gets me the virtual host.

Can some please explain why:

- the change to the virtual host file has the impact it does.
- what is the correct configuration.
- I can't access either server from the virtual host machine with with either configuration using `1.2.3.4`.

This is driving me nuts. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: do you want to access your vhost by IP (http://1.2.3.4 and http://192.168.0.2), or just by domain-name?

Comment: @VladimirDimitrov Both, really.

Comment: specifying 1.2.3.4 in virtualhost directive makes no sense, because this IP is not assign directly on the vhost machine. Accessing apache by IP opens default virtual host, if you want to access your vhost by 1.2.3.4, 192.168.0.2 and by domain name you have to point default DocumentRoot  and ServerName to your vhost's docroot and name, or to place your site in current DocumentRoot (where "It works" page stands). Do note that in this way you don't use NameVirual host, the point of NameVirtualHosts is to have multiple sites sharing single IP, so you have to access them by domain name not by IP

Comment: @Vladimir-Dimitrov I supposed something like that :-(( so the apache vhost must remain standard config (the first in the question) and the config must be done in the adsl router... But how to? Thank you for hints